# How can I couple 50Hz/60hz mains interference to a signal cable in practice?

Tags: noise

I want to create a 50Hz noise on signal transmission line options which are a coaxial cable with BNC connectors and the other is an STP cable with BNC connector. Cables are like 10 meters long or more.

As receiver system I have two data-acq. systems, where one is single-ended input and the other is diff-input.

Imagine the output impedance of the source is balanced or neglect it.

So there are four combinations:

Coaxial to single ended daq

Coaxial to diff ended daq

STP to single ended daq

STP to diff ended daq

I want to experiment and demonstrate these in case of 50Hz interference.

But I dont know how can I create 50Hz interference on the lines.

How can I couple a significant 50Hz magnetic inference to a cable in practice? Is there an easy practical way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I couple a significant 50Hz magnetic inference to a cable in
>   practice? Is there an easy practical way?

I don't know about an "easy" way but you could use a three winding transformer with windings in series with signal and return wire (shield/screen) and the third winding excited with a 50 Hz voltage: -

[image]

You can "inject" at the source end or the receiver end to suit the configuration of your cables. The circuit above creates a common-mode voltage and that is what I believe you are looking for.

The signal source (50 Hz) needn't be connected to earth - it can be isolated but it was convenient to show it this way. The signal source could be the low voltage output from a seperate mains powered transformer.

Comment: Could you also add an illustration for the coaxial case? Im asking because this is a bit higher voltage stuff. Thanks

Comment: Are the terminals of 50Hz source 230V  line and neutral in your figure?

Comment: No more pictures - you interrupt the screen/shield of the coax. The 50 Hz voltage signal can be anything you want but bear in mind safety and the step-down ratio you need to obtain the CM signal you require.

Comment: I will try these